# How to strip quotes from a string

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I wrote a simple rule to match a string in an ANTLR grammar:

```
STRING
   :   '"' (ESC | ~["\\])* '"'
   ;
```

Actually I need the content of the string and not the quotes, which are only required to match a string.

I found a solution for ANTLR 3, [which is published in the ANTLR wiki](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/x/HgAp). But I would like to know if there is a solution to achive the same without custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
STRING
   :   '"' (ESC | ~["\\])* '"'
   {setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));}
   ;
```

It simple removes the first and last character from the string.

Taken from https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687006/How+do+I+strip+quotes

Comment: has there been update in antlr4 to deal with this within lexer rule? I'd also like to avoid using actions.